# Landscape how to send email from landscape

Tags: landscape

How do i send a test email with landscape?

I'm running it on a local server that has postfix configured, tested and working. But i want to test landscape notifications. I tried to test by sending a administrator inventation to my email. I got no errors, but i didn't get the email inbox or spam.

Test messages work from the console with:
`echo "body of your email" | mail -s "This is a Subject" -a "From: someemail@somedomain.com" myemail@gmail.com`

Any idea why landscape email not working or what log to look at to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was in my mail logs.

`tail /var/log/mail.log -f` showed a error `Invalid FROM email address "noreply@myservername"` I changed that to be a valid domain (`noreply@something.com`) in landscape settings and the problem was resolved.